# How to get value js website module in odoo?

Tags: javascript, web, odoo

I want if note field have value, make alert.
My code is:

```
odoo.define('website_sale_product_list.product', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    var ajax = require('web.ajax');
    $(window).load(function(){
      console.log('dg');
       var note = $('#note').val();
       console.log(note + '        note');
       var comment = document.getElementById("note").value;
       if( comment != null && comment != undefined) {
            alert(comment);
        }
        else {
            alert(comment + '       0');
        }

   });
});
```

Note value is undefined. Help, i need any solution?

Comment: what is your note in HTML?

Comment: <td>
       <h4 t-field="product.comment" id="note"></h4>
 </td>

Comment: I hope there is something with $window.load function. try changing this to $(window).on("load",function(){
console.log('dg');
       var note = $('#note').val();
       console.log(note + '        note');
       var comment = document.getElementById("note").value;
       if( comment != null && comment != undefined) {
            alert(comment);
        }
        else {
            alert(comment + '       0');
        }
});

Comment: Thanks, but not working . The console log is comment **undefined**. How to solve?